# Bot Emulator login

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I'm trying to add authentication to my bot so it can access the Graph. I am using the tutorial from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp ,

with the sample "C# Auth Graph". I did test the connection of the Bot Channel Registration in Azure. Everything fine. Now the problem -> When i start the program (using the emulator) and it prompts me to login, it shows me this :

[image]

What could I do to fix this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added the OAuth key in the Bot Channels Registration??

Comment: yep everything like in the tutorial

Comment: Double check the tenant and scopes on your OAuth setup. The bot is actually working as expected in your picture, but your oauth is not connecting to the right auth service provider from the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine saw this and pointed out that your Ngrok is not configured for the emulator. If you add ngrok to the emulator, it will solve this problem.